# Why can't ASP.NET API be accessed via external ip?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, server

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 instance and I wanted to deploy an ASP.NET Web API to it (I have used custom deployment method, saving the .rar file on disk). I have created the website inside IIS and everything is working great on http://localhost:8080.

When I try to access it by its external ip (http://12.34.567.899:8080) it won't respond.
Also, the default website on port 80 is fully working.

## Things that I have tried

**1. My port is open as I have run 'netstat -a' and port 8080 shows as 'LISTENING'**

**2. I have already checked bindings for IIS, they are ':8080'**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This could be any number of things. Is this in a colo or provider like AWS? Do you have ipsec configured correctly in iis? A firewall could be the issue. Regardless of your site, can you reach the machine externally at all? You need to provide more info.

Comment: it's inside aws and ipsec is by default, haven't made any changes

Comment: only 80 and 443 are exposed in aws.

Comment: You can still publish your website under "Default web site" which runs on port 80 by default. or if there's nothing on Default webs site remove its mapping to port 80 and change it to something else. Create a new website in IIS root and map it port 80. Deploy your website on new Website. This should work.

Comment: This question is probably better suited for serverfault. Also, it seems this question has been asked many times there. i.e. http://serverfault.com/questions/317903/aws-ec2-open-port-8080

Comment: @Josh. C does that mean 8080 will not work with aws? For Inbound rules under security groups I have added TCP access for 8080 from any IP.